# algoritmo que llene la diagonal principal de la matriz con los números 1,2,3,...N. LENGUAJE C

Tags: c

Necesito llenar la diagonal principal de la matriz. He logrado que se llene pero... en algunas posiciones de la matriz se desborda con números muy grandes, en vez de que sean `0`.

```
main(){
  int i,j,k,valor=0,b;

  printf("\n **  Digite el tamaño de la matriz\n");

  scanf("%d",&k);

  int M[k][k];

  for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    for(j=0;j<k;j++){
      if(i == j){
        valor++;
        M[i][j] = valor;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\n ** NUMEROS de Diagonal principal de la matriz\n");
  for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    printf("  %d  ",M[i][i]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");
  printf("\n ** MATRIZ \n");
  printf("\n\n");
  for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    for(j=0;j<k;j++){
      printf("  %d  ",M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main()` debe ser `int main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> en vez de que sean 0

Pero es que tú **nunca** les asignas ese `0` que esperas.

El estándar dicta que toda variable, **antes de asignarle un valor**, contiene un valor *indefinido*. Y tu, simplemente, no estás asignado valor a todos los elementos de tu *array* `M`. Solo lo asignas a los elementos que se encuentran en la *matriz principal*, dejando los demás, precisamente, con ese valor indefinido. Por eso esos números *raros* que te aparecen.

Simplemente, asigna valores a **todas** las posiciones del *array*:

```
...

for(i=0;i<k;i++){
  for(j=0;j<k;j++){
    if(i == j){
      valor++;
      M[i][j] = valor;
    } else {
      M[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

...
```